# how to pull from a private registry in gitlab CI, with docker DIND

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-in-docker

actually I'm using gitlab runners, with docker executor, and I'm trying to pull some docker images to do some tests, and to preserve my network connection, I've created a private docker registry, to "cache" the images .

So, my registry is linked to my gitlab runner (with configuration in the config.toml https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section ) .

This work, my image can ask the registry :

```
$ wget http://registry:5000/v2/_catalog

--2019-02-15 10:40:54--  http://registry:5000/v2/_catalog
Resolving registry... 172.17.0.3
Connecting to registry|172.17.0.3|:5000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 20 [application/json]
Saving to: '_catalog'

     0K                                                       100% 1.17M=0s

2019-02-15 10:40:54 (1.17 MB/s) - '_catalog' saved [20/20]
```

but the DIND service can't :

```
pull registry:5000/arminc/clair-db:latest
Error response from daemon: Get http://registry:5000/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry on 192.168.9.254:53: no such host
```

My gitlab-ci conf for this task

```
scan:image:
  stage: scans
  image: docker:git
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
      command: ["--insecure-registry=registry:5000"]
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - chmod 777 ./docker/scan.sh
    - docker login -u $DOCKER_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD $DOCKER_REGISTRY
    - ./docker/scan.sh
  artifacts:
    paths: [gl-container-scanning-report.json]
  only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you might need to add a DNS entry to your DNS server or dockers host file:

```
192.168.xx.xxx registry
```